# Utilizing Azure Database Backup, How Many Simultaneous Restores Allowed?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We are trying to restore one database backup, stored in Azure, to multiple SQL instances at the same time and are running into issues, getting error descriptions like "Desc=Open devices!" and "Desc=Create Memory. ErrorCode=(5)Access is denied.". 
Is this possible? Or do they need to be restored successively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Azure has logic to do various operations online/automatically for you (copy databases, restore databases, backups, upgrades, etc.). Some operations are limited to 25 in parallel. There are IOs required to do each operation, so there are limits in place because the machine does not have infinite IOPS. (Those limits may change a bit over time as Microsoft improve the service, get newer hardware, etc.).

You can restore in parallel N databases from a database backup but still you have the IOPS limit. You can try a larger reservation size for the source and target during restore operations to get more IOPS and lower the time to perform the operations.

Try to create a bacpac of the database you want to restore and mix restore from backups with restore from bacpacs in parallel to workaround limits without adding IOPS and increasing costs.

Comment: After some more testing, we've determined that restoring from Azure is prohibitively slow for one database, let alone multiple. Our system is currently backing up our databases to both Azure and our file system so we've decided to restore from the file system after making that path available to the instances in question. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the solution you choose in the end.